# How to update numpy array based based on coordinates

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, computer-vision

I have an image that is given as below, which I am trying to convert into a binary image.

To convert this image into a binary image, I did:

```
image[image > 0] = 255
```

This creates a binary image with colored region having only white pixels. But I also want to convert the pixels that are above the colored region to value 255. How could I do this? I do not only want to convert the colored pixels to white but also the area above it. Is there I could do this? The area denoted by arrows will remain black (i.e area after the colored region)

[image]

**UPDATE**
Also, how could I approach if the edges are as shown below:

[image]

Comment: image[image >= 0] = 255? Can you be more specific? The question makes it sound like you want to both remove and keep the black pixels.

Comment: I don't understand this: "the pixels that are above the colored region"

Comment: @Joshua I want to keep all the black pixels on the right side of the image but convert everything else including the small black strip on the top to white.

Comment: @Mehdi  I want to keep all the black pixels on the right side of the image but convert everything else including the small black strip on the top to white.

Comment: @Amanda, could you share an example of images you are manipulating. Because I think here you are referring to something in the image  "the small black strip on the top to white"

Comment: Is this the image including the arrows? https://i.stack.imgur.com/hp8my.jpg 
Or you are trying to say something with the arrows?

Comment: @Mehdi Image does not include arrows. By arrow I meant that I want to retain the black pixels on the right part of image and convert everything else to white (which also includes the black strip at the top)

Comment: @Amanda Okay, you use array slicing for this try something like image[0:100, :] = 255, this would convert the first 100 rows to white

Comment: @Joshua I think the problem that Amanda is explaining is more difficult. The line between black and white is tilted. Even if we find the line, we have to infer the continuation of it as the line between black and white. Am I correct?

Comment: @Mehdi Yes, you are correct

Comment: Not sure I follow. But perhaps you want two lines: `image[image > x] = 255` to make the white and `image[image <=  x] = 0` to make the black, where grayscale value x could be 0 or any value between 0 and 255.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly your problem a more elaborated approach should be taken to get the desired result.

First of all the approach to use a simple threshold creates a noisy approach.

I used a modified image of your sample:
[image]

If you apply your thresholding then a result like this might come up:
[image]

A finer thresholding can be useful here:

```
image3 = cv2.inRange(image, np.array([10, 10, 10]), np.array([255, 255, 255]))
```

which creates a binary image as a result (resembles your desired output except for the upper strip):
[image]

TO get rid of the strip I would (it's just an approach not the perfect one though) use something to find the corner created by the white region and then use it to draw all the region above it with black:

```
ind = np.where(image3 == 255)
max_x = np.max(ind[1])
max_y = ind[0][np.argmax(ind[1])]
image3[:max_y, :max_x] = 255
```

And the result would be like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

By all mean this is not the perfect answer. But it might be something helpful.

I recreated the image as follows:

[image: test image]

Then I read it and followed your path with making it binary first (with a small modification to reduce noises):

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = plt.imread("sample.jpg")
img2 = img.copy()
img2[img2.sum(-1) > 30] = 255
img2[img2.sum(-1) <= 30] = 0
```

Here is the result after this modification:

[image: figure one]

**OPTION 1**

This might not be what you asked but it is similar to one of the solutions discussed in the comments, and I think it is partly correct:

```
i, j = np.where(img2.sum(-1) > 0) # find all white coordinates
i, j = (i[j.argmax()], j[j.argmax()]) # the corner white point into the black
img2[:i, :j] = 255 # paint whine all the left-above rectangle from this point
```

Here is the final result:

[image: the final graph]

This is an imperfect but pretty simple pure numpy solution.

**OPTION 2**

In this solution, we need some simple calculus and linear algebra. Take two points in 2D space and draw a line between them. So, what is the function of the borderline?

```
point2 = (i, j) # same i and j from OPTION1 (coordinates of the top-right corner)
point1 = (img2.shape[0], img2[-1].sum(-1).argmin()) # the bottom-right white corner.

a = (point2[1] - point1[1]) / (point2[0] - point1[0])
c = point1[1] - a * point1[0]
f = lambda x: int(a * x + c)
```

Now, paint all areas to the left of the line:

```
for i in range(img2.shape[0]):
    img2[:i, :f(i)+1] = 255
```

Here is the result:
[image]

Comment: Is there also a way to smooth the steps (zig-zag lines) as shown?

Comment: A common solution to smooth zigzag edges is anti-aliasing but it is contradictory to binary images because it requires gray pixels.